# rStudio mirror calls

Tags: r, console

Trying to compile Report from R script to a Ms word file, but every time I try to I get this in the R markdown

[image]

Comment: Hi Oda. What is your line of code with `contrib.url()` that is causing this error?

Comment: I used install.packages("readxl") and I think it may have to do with importing a file and .rmd. But I am not sure

Comment: Don't include that that command in a Rmd document. You only need to install a package once.